# Android Firebase Crash Reporting difference between Log and Logcat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I am trying to log the error from my app, so I am using the firebase custom logs.

But I found this two as log and logcat.

```
public static void log(java.lang.String s)
```

and other is,

```
public static void logcat(int i,
                          java.lang.String s,
                          java.lang.String s1)
```

So what is difference and which should I prefer to use?

Answer (score 2):

> *static void  log(String message)*
> Logs a message that will appear in a subsequent crash report.
>
> *static void  logcat(int level, String tag, String message)*
> Logs a message that will appear in a subsequent crash report as well as in logcat.

You should check their documentation
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/crash/FirebaseCrash